# Vue.js - class binding on a component via prop

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to pass into a component, via prop, a `color` attribute, which will determine the background color of the component. The choices for the `color` attribute are 'red' and 'blue'.

The actual component is set up as the following:

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
    props: ['color'],
    template: '<div v-bind:class="{'add-red': color === 'red', 'add-blue': color === 'blue'}" class="box"></div>'
});
```

The actual `color` is passed in as follows:

```
<component color='red' :is='currentComponent'></component>
```

But I can't seem to get the class binding to work in my jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/cckLd9te/3217/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is mixing between single quote `'` and double quote `"`. You should use escape character

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
    props: ['color'],
  template: '<div v-bind:class="{\'add-red\': color === \'red\', \'add-blue\': color === \'blue\'}" class="box"></div>'
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/de1yhq5r/)